# Python: Define a class with properties that either return value, or call another class variable

Tags: python

I am probably doing this the wrong way, but here we go...  I am trying to make a class like:

```
class MyMainClass():
    def __init__(self, x: pd.DataFrame, y : pd.DataFrame):
        self._x = x 
        self._y = y 
        
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
```

Where I'm having trouble, is I basically want to wrap the variables x, y in another class that contains a class method

```
class SpecialClass():    
    def __init__(self, x_or_y):
        self.x_or_y = x_or_y
    
    @property # or maybe its something else?
    def to_matrix(self):                
       # do some stuff
       return manipulated_x_or_y
```

And really the whole reason I'm doing this is to make it easier for the downstream user to later one do things like

```
mainclass = MainClass(x, y)
print(mainclass.x)  #prints the original dataframe

print(mainclass.x.to_matrix)  # prints the new dataframe
```

Comment: `mainclass.x` is not an instance of `SpecialClass`, so you can't use `to_matrix` there.

Comment: So `self._x = SpecialClass(x); self._y = SpecialClass(y)`?

Comment: Yup exactly that!